# How to change the login message in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-1.3

I use CakePHP 1.3 and I want to change this message:

> You are not authorized to access that location.

to (for example):

> oh sorry

The message appears from this code:

> echo $this->Session->flash('auth');

i change app_controller to

```
class AppController extends Controller {

var $components = array('Auth', 'Session', 'Acl');

function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->authorize = 'actions';
    $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
    if ($this->params['controller'] == 'pages') {
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
    }
    $this->Auth->allow('pages');
    $this->Auth->loginError = "This message shows up when the wrong credentials are used";    
    $this->Auth->authError = "This error shows up with the user tries to access a part of the website that is protected.";

}
```

}

but yet i face same message.

Comment: i add your code like a bow but i face same message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this happens, you probably have explicitly included the AuthComponent in your UsersController as well. Make sure to set the `authError` in the UsersController beforeFilter method as well or make sure that it's beforeFilter calls `parent::beforeFilter()` to include the message.

Answer (score 5):

This way:

```
$this->Auth->loginError = "This message shows up when the wrong credentials are used";  
$this->Auth->authError = "This error shows up with the user tries to access a part of the website that is protected.";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can customize this on `beforeFilter` like

```
function beforeFilter() {
  // ...
  $this->Auth->authError = __('You must be logged in to view this page.');
  $this->Auth->loginError = __('Invalid Username or Password entered, please try again.');
}
```

OR

There's another way to make the Auth component more personalized.

Go to:

```
/cake/libs/controller/components/auth.php
```

And find `function __setDefaults()`.

You can customized error message here for entire application.